# How to select multiple rows based on AND condition on a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, rdbms

I am trying something like:

```
select name from myTable where id in (1056,1066,1069,1080,1404,1406,1407,3018)
```

But this is acting like OR condition and if I use AND between these values it does not give any result as it is trying to match in one cell.

Sample Data:

```
Name ID :   abc 1 |abc 2| abc 3| def 2| fgh 3
```

My expected output is:

```
Name: abc
```

I want to find all the distinct names
 having all corresponding ID's
Any pointer on this?

Comment: `how this is possible : an id have 8 values at the same time in a specific record?`

Comment: So what is your actual goal?

Comment: Data exists in the table like this:
Name   ID
abc       1056|
abc       1066|
abc       1069|

In my db, I have many records which contain all the corresponding ids as mentioned above, So I want to find all the distinct names having all those ids

Comment: Kindly provide some sample data and expected result.

Comment: A great way to share information with us is with http://sqlfiddle.com/.  You can set up the table with actual values for us to see.

Comment: Please add some sample data.

Comment: @wewesthemenace
here is the sample data. I need Abc as my result
Name ID
Abc 1
Abc 2
Abc 3
Def 2
Def 3
Fgh 1
lets if I have ID values as (1,2,3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the problem of this type, the best solution I could is use divide feature of Relational Algebra.
It will give the expected result.
Sample Example:-
http://coronet.iicm.tugraz.at/Dbase1/scripts/rdbh06.htm

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are confused on Logic, if you use AND then condition becomes false because there will not be any single row with  ID having 1056 AND 1066.

for eg. suppose you have this table

```
ID    name level
----------------
1056  abc  bce

1066  bcd  def
```

```
select name from myTable where id =1056 AND id=1066
```

now evaluate this with first row replacing id

```
1056 =1056 AND 1056=1066  (True AND False) is False
1066 =1056 AND 1066=1066  (False AND True) is False
```

So condition never becomes true so no rows are selected

**Update**
As per as your updated question, write like this

```
select distinct name from myTable where id in (1056,1066,1069,1080,1404,1406,1407,3018)
```

Comment: I got your point. I have understood this thing. That's why asking here for alternative approach.
Pls see my updated question

Answer (score 0):

Ew.  Multiple values in the same field?

```
select name from myTable 
where id like '%1056%'
or id like '%1066%'
or id like '%1069%'
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

`Logically there is no output of your query`, but if you want to use `multiple AND`s once without writing writing `AND` multiple times, you can use [Row Subqueries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/row-subqueries.html):

```
select name 
from myTable 
where (id,id,id,id,id,id,id,id)=(1056,1066,1069,1080,1404,1406,1407,3018)
```

is equal to:

```
select name 
from myTable 
where id =1056 
      AND   id =1066
      AND   id =1069
      AND   id =1080
      AND   id =1404
      AND   id =1406
      AND   id =1407
      AND   id =3018
```